# What are the keys to *high-quality* sound and video recording?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 20.04, video, jack

Setup is a new system76 Darter laptop, running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit; Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 audio interface and an AudioTechnica AT2020 condenser mic.

I tried making a video recording of myself playing the piano using Cheese, and the sound is crappy--distorted on anything above average volume. Reducing the gain on the AI had no effect. As near as I can tell from listening to the AI's monitor port, the distortion doesn't come from the AI.

I'm looking at various packages, but it seems like high-quality audio is found only in DAWs like Audacity and screen-recording software like OBS. This is a case where I don't care much about the video quality, don't even care about synching, but I'd really like to have sound that doesn't get fuzzy when the levels get a little high. And I don't want to get involved with screen recording, this is more a home-movie situation.

TIA for any suggestions.

Comment: No, the mic is plugged into the AI, which talks to the computer via USB, and the sound as heard through the AI's monitor is fine. Since posting I tried the same setup with my old Lenovo running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS; the sound is good. I exported a file recorded on the new laptop from mkv to mp3 and listened to it on my phone--same problem. Something on the new box is munging audio input.
The new box differs not only in age and version but in sound drivers, I just installed Qtcreator and JACK as part of the underpinning for Jamulus. For all I know the sound recording was fine before that.

Comment: Nothing wrong with audacity, or anything else--the problem was my input levels were set too high. The problem/misconfiguration was common to the built-in mic too. PulseAudioVU was a big help, helped me see and fix the settings. Thanks for your suggestions. I should have known from the fuzz tone (exactly like a fuzz bass with the built-in mic) that it was overdriving distortion.